Python.h - No such file or directory with python3-dev installed
I'm trying to install mod_wsgi, and I get this error: src/server/wsgi_python.h:26:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
I've searched for the Python.h file, and it's clearly there, so I tried including it by typing make -I /usr/include/python3.11, but it still doesn't work :/

There is probably another Python version installed on your system, that is found and used by mod_wsgi when building itself. Three questions: 1/ What does which python give you? 2/ What system are you on? 3/ How do you install mod_wsgi?

Also, it might be useful to post the full traceback (or for a very large traceback, the first 10-20 lines and the last 50 lines or so) of the error.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Nevermind, I've solved the issue.
I was installing using the installation guide on mod_wsgi website, but I didn't realize that I can just install it with apt :)
